# focusing textbox in the rightmost digit

Tags: vb.net

how do i code this in vb.net:

**focus the textbox and get the cursor to the rightmost digit?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a WindowsForm you can use:

```
Me.TextBox1.Focus()
Me.TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length
```

In a WebForm you can set the focus using a javascript function like this:

```
function setCursorPosition(elemId, cursorPosition) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elemId);
    if(element != null) {
        if(element.selectionStart) {
            element.focus();
            element.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
        }
        else
            element.focus();
    }
}
```