# VB.NET Prevent Button gain focus

Tags: .net, vb.net, controls

I just developed a custom control ( pic below )

[image]

its a " mini On Screen KeyBoard " =) now up to this i placed a simple TextBox and i filled all button of the keyboard with sendkeys code

```
    Private Sub BTN4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN4.Click
         SendKeys.Send("4")
    End Sub
```

the problem is that if I click one of the buttons, the textbox is not written, this is because the button takes the focus before sending the character!

I googled a lot without any result, so I started to comb through MSDN looking for something useful, and I found this

```
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, False)
```

still does not work. Can you help me in any way? I'm working on a project that should deliver short and I am very angry because I can not solve a problem such an idiot!

Thanks for everything

Comment: Is the textbox in a separate application? Why do you need to use SendKeys instead of modifying its text directly?

Comment: because i want to create a reusable control =) if i bind it to a simple textbox when i need to use it in another app i cant =P

Comment: As long as you're reusing it within the same app that contains the textbox, you can just pass the control object a reference to the desired textbox (for example, in the constructor, or as a separate property). SendKeys is rather fragile; I recommend not using it unless you have to.

Answer (score 1):

In your Sub, before `SendKeys.Send("4")`, insert the following lines:

```
Me.TextBox1.Focus()
Me.TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length
```

Where `TextBox1` is the name of your textbox.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/861625/662761)

Comment: Yes, this can be a good exploits ! but I would like to know if there is a way to include this function in the Custom Control, so you do not have to edit the individual sub =)
Thank you Jack

Comment: You could use the textbox's `LostFocus` event to return focus. Or, build the string yourself and avoid using `SendKeys` altogether.

Comment: I forgot to say that what you see is not a custom control, but is a series of controls that inherit from Windows.Forms.Button, I do not know what will be the value of that button, if "a", "b" or "c "so I can not return the value, unless I insert a property specific to this, which I prefer not to do.

I try to change the focus of the textbox, let's see if it works correctly! although I hope to find another way, I still do not understand why the SetStyle does not work! pff

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a keyboard Control with **events** and declare it with WithEvents key ? Then declare in your keyboard control the following events :

```
Public Class CustomKeyboardControl

    Inherits Control

    Public Event KeyboardButtonPressed(ByVal KeyValue As String)

    ' ...

    ' And on click event for each of your buttons :
    Private Sub BTN4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN4.Click
         RaiseEvent KeyboardButtonPressed("4")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Finally, in your application that uses this custom keyboard control, just add an handler.

```
Public Class MyForm
    Private WithEvents MyKeyboard As New CustomKeyboardControl()
    ' Should be declared in your Designer...
    ' Just add the "WithEvents" if that declaration...

    Private Sub HandleKeyboardInputs(ByVal KeyValue As String) Handles MyKeyboard.KeyboardButtonPressed
        MyTextBox.Text = MyTextBox.Text + KeyValue
        ' Of course, you can use SelectionStart/SelectionLength (...)
        ' to replace or insert the input at the correct place
        ' without forgetting to update the values of SelectionStart and SelectionLength...
    End Sub

    ' ...

End Class
```

This approach let you to you use you Keyboard control in many different situations...

Hope this helps. I could see you are actually using an Android-like layout... In that case, I don't think my idea is better...